# How to define current year as a variable in proc fedsql

Tags: sql, sas

How can I define the current year in proc fedsql?
I tried

```
%let td=%sysfunc(today(),date9.);
%put &td;
%let current_year = year(&td);
%put &current_year;
```

which doesn't evaluate and

```
%let td=%sysfunc(today(),date9.);
%put &td;
%let current_year = %eval(year(&td));
%put &current_year;
```

which gives me the error
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: year(24JUL2023)

Comment: what SQL are you using ?

Comment: I am using Proc fedsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `year(current_date)`

```
proc fedsql;
    select year(current_date) as "year", *
    from have
    ;
quit;
```

[Documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_041/fedsqlref/n0t7xulj9hno5an1891od2so3tyb.htm)